# Renaming "product", "price" and "quantity" in cart page of WordPress WooCommerce website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How do I rename the text that shows up in the cart page on the WordPress WooCommerce platform?

Specifically I want to rename "product", "price", and "quantity".
I want to rename "product" to something else and so on.

Comment: What do you want to rename them to, and why do you want to rename them?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I can understand why, instead of products a user may be booking a tutor, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by editing `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php`

There appears to be 2 locations where you would need to change it.  In version 3.8.0 it is lines 30 and 77 for "Product".

e.g. `<th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>`  However note that this is using WPML to translate, so if your site is loaded in another language, your new string may not translate.

Also, you need to keep in mind that when woocommerce updates your changes may be lost.

Woocommerce say:

> This template can be overridden by copying it to
> yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php.
>
> - HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your
>   theme to maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as
>   possible, but it does happen. When this occurs the version of the
>   template file will be bumped and the readme will list any important
>   changes.